# NotePad++: styling the text before the assignment in an INI file

Tags: notepad++

Using the **Style Configurator**, Notepad++ does not have a preference to change the style of text before a colon `:` or equals sign `=` in an `*.ini` file. It is a trivial detail, but it would help make overlooking configuration files a lot easier.

[image: style] [image: example]

`DEFAULT`, `COMMENT`, `SECTION`, `ASSIGNMENT`, or `DEFVAL` does not modify the text before the colon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the following property to the `<LexerType name="ini" desc="ini file">` block in **stylers.xml** does the trick!

```
<WordsStyle name="KEYWORD" styleID="5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
```

Now you can modify the `KEYWORD` entry to change the style of text before the colon.

[image: keyword] [image: result]

Comment: How np++ knows that KEYWORD is the parte before the ":" or "="?